# Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: sandbox, change-set, visibility

I am probably missing something very basic but I can't spot it.
I get this error when I try to upload a change set to production:

> CaseCommentHandler: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: CaseTriggerHandler.createRecordTypeIdHelper(String) 
>           Stack Trace: null

**CaseCommentHandler**

```
    public class CaseCommentHandler extends TriggerHandler {
       private void caseCommentMethod() {
           ...
           id security = CaseTriggerHandler.createRecordTypeIdHelper('Security'); //This is where the deployment fails
           ...
       }
    }
```

**CaseTriggerHandler:**

```
public class CaseTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandler {
    public static Id createRecordTypeIdHelper (String input){
        Id tempId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(input).getRecordTypeId();
        return tempId;
    }
}
```

The class is working fine on Sandbox and also, when I deployed a cloned version of this change set to another sandbox  which was refreshed a few days ago (I run all the local tests), it deployed successfully.

Comment: Did you actually include both classes?

Comment: Everything looks correct to me... Maybe double check whether "Security" is the Name field of the record type, not the DeveloperName. I've often accidentally passed "Car_Manufacturer" in instead of "Car Manufacturer". The user friendly label version is the correct one. But being one word, I imagine they're the same value for your record type.

Comment: @AdrianLarson sorry if I wasn't clear. these two classes were already in production. my issue was when I tried to upload a change set that only contained the CaseTriggerHandler out of the two and a few other classes, the error appeared.
my workaround was simple, I uploaded a different version of CaseCommentHandler without referencing createRecordTypeIdHelper. But I still want to know why I got this error on the first place.

Comment: @caleb.breckon - I checked it, it's Security but tnx anyway